# ALM Process Automation

Tags: rest, automation, alm

We are using HP ALM for QC in our projects and we are planning to automate the following things uisng HP ALM's REST api.

1.Dynamically upload the test cases in Test Plan and Test lab.-From the api code sample i can understand that TC's are upload to Test lab by creating test set folders.But how to upload the TC's in Test plan ?

2. Map the test cases in Test plan and Test lab -No where i have seen any examples which explains how to map the TC's in Test Plan and Lab.

3.Dynamically update the  status of the test cases with Success or failure.

4.How to map the TC's with work items ?

Can you please advise us that the above items are achievable ?

Comment: Please have a look at [Agiletestware Bumblebee](https://www.agiletestware.com/bumblebee) and [Agiletestware Dragonfly](https://www.agiletestware.com/dragonfly) products - probably they fit your needs for HP ALM integrations.

Answer (score 0):

of course what you mentioned is possible. First of all it may be different on the HP QC REST ALM version you are using. For instance not all the features are enabled on the first 11.x version, but most of bugs got fixed in the 12.53 for instance.

Anyway coming to your point:

1) Always refer to the HP REST ALM library to check the REST msg you should send:
http://alm-help.saas.hpe.com/en/12.53/api_refs/REST/#Overview.htm

2) You have to choose a way to send and receive those msgs. Nowadays it is quite common the usage of python (I am using that). Please have a look at the "REQUESTS" module that will fit for this task!
First action is to login/authenticate into the QC ALM, then you can start sending next operation according to the library above and keeping the correct information in the header (for instance the LSSOCookie).

3) Plenty of questions are already answered on stackOverflow. Always try to check a specific task.

4) Coming to your questions: if test-set-folders is used for folders in test lab, then test-folders is used as entity for the folder under Test Plan.

Entity= "test-instances" is used then to link a Test Case to Test Set :-)

To update a test-set or test-case you have to send a proper update for that. (some bugs are visible in that area for the HP 11.52 --> for instance before create a test as "No-run" and then update to "pass or fail". This you will experience after you have implemented first points.

you can then create run, run-steps, design-steps, attached files and whatever is mentioned on the HP ALM library.

Please vote the question if this solved your query ;) that you can close the same! I wish you luck in your project! ciao ciao!